# MMC 3.0 snap in development and 'connect to another computer...' dialog

Tags: .net-3.5, mmc, mmc3, snap-in

I'm in the process of developing a custom [MMC 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms692755(VS.85).aspx) snap-in and was wondering if there is some built in SDK/API way of connecting to another computer running the same snap-in?  If so, can someone provide some code samples or links to tutorials on how this is possible?  If it is not possible, what do you recommend to use for communicating with other machines? Would there need to be a separate service on the remote machine to accept and propagate the actions taken on the remote instance?  Any help on this would be great.

**Thank you,**

Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the "Connect to another computer..." is implemented by Window's 'Computer Management' snapin, not MMC.

As for how to communicate with other machines, there's various options. You'll need to give more detail about what you want to do and what tools you are using, in order to get some suggestions.

Comment: Thanks, I figured this was the case, but I wanted to verify.  I am trying to connect and manage similarly to how VMWare vCenter (http://www.run-virtual.com/files/perf2.gif) manages host machines.  Basically, I want to connect from one machine and manage a complex distributed application from one centralized point.  Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which module you load in MMC, you could "Connect to Another Computer".  I was able to connect to another computer after I loaded the Certificates MMC -- at the Certificates level, you can see the option.

Comment: I was writing a custom MMC plugin.  Telling me that you can do what I am asking to do on specific native MMC plugins, doesn't help.