# How MMC snap-ins expose remote capabilites

Tags: c#, .net, remote-access, mmc, snap-in

I have built a custom MMC snap-in, and I was wondering what the standard way is to extend my snap-in to have remote capabilities. For example, the default Windows Event Viewer snap-in allows you to connect to `Another computer` when you add it into your MMC snap-in list:

[image]

It also exposes a right-click context menu that lets you `Connect to Another Computer...`:

[image]

How is this generally achieved with MMC snap-ins? Is there a generic API for this or a standard way to get this functionality out of a custom snap-in?

Ideally, I just want to have one MMC window manage the same snap-in for multiple remote servers (saves the user the trouble of manually RDPing into them and using MMC remotely for each machine).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282275/mmc-3-0-snap-in-development-and-connect-to-another-computer-dialog edit: nevermind, no real answers there.

Comment: @CodeCaster I can think of a multitude of ways of doing it but surely there is some sort of protocol used for this purpose in MMC's native snap-ins.